# Java - RestAPI - Patch not working efficiently

Tags: java, rest

I've a small problem with my method using protocol PATCH in my RestController, I'm creating an object Warehouse.

1st I'm creating it via POST:

```
{
    "location" : "Paris",
    "maxCapacity" : "200"
}
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": "Paris",
        "currentCapacity": 0,
        "maxCapacity": 200,
        "cargosList": [],
        "status": "EMPTY"
    }
]
```

When for example, PATCHing only field location:

```
{
    "location" : "New York"
}
```

And when reading with GET:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "location": "New York",
        "currentCapacity": 0,
        "maxCapacity": null,
        "cargosList": [],
        "status": "EMPTY"
    }
]
```

Why the field maxCapacity have been changed to null although my PATCH request was only on field location?

My Entity:

```
package net.erickcaron.warehouseapplicationapi.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity(name = "warehouses")
public class Warehouse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String location;
    private Integer currentCapacity = 0;
    private Integer maxCapacity;

    @OneToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Cargo> cargosList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private WarehouseStatus status = WarehouseStatus.EMPTY;


}
```

My RestController:

```
package net.erickcaron.warehouseapplicationapi.rest;

import net.erickcaron.warehouseapplicationapi.models.Warehouse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import net.erickcaron.warehouseapplicationapi.services.WarehouseService;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/warehouses")
public class WarehouseRestController {

    @Autowired
    private WarehouseService warehouseService;

    @PostMapping
    public Integer create(@RequestBody Warehouse warehouse){
        return warehouseService.create(warehouse);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Warehouse findById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return warehouseService.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Warehouse> findAll(){
        return warehouseService.findAll();
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}") //TODO not working!
    public void partialUpdate(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Warehouse warehouse){
        warehouseService.partialUpdate(id, warehouse);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        warehouseService.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{warehouseId}/cargos/{cargoId}")
    public void addCargoToWarehouse(@PathVariable Integer warehouseId, @PathVariable Integer cargoId){
        warehouseService.addCargoToWarehouse(warehouseId, cargoId);
    }






}
```

Thanks for any help,
Regards,
Erick

Comment: Obviously your `warehouseService.partialUpdate()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Can you post warehouseService.partialUpdate() source code ?

Comment: Here it is: public void partialUpdate(Integer id, Warehouse warehouse) {
        findById(id);
        warehouse.setId(id);
        warehouseRepository.save(warehouse);
    }

I think that I even by myself understood the issue at this point.. but not sure about resolution..

Comment: Is there any needs to iterate threw the new warehouse object from Request Body, comparing it to the actual one on DB, and if fields are differents, replace their values from actual one on DB to new warehouse object from Request Body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `mapper` to update your Entity and then persist it again. I can more than recommend [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)!

You can create a `Mapper` this way:

```java
@Mapper
public interface WarehouseMapper {
    
    // Ignore null Values
    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    void updateWarehouse(Warehouse updatedWarehouse, @MappingTarget Warehouse oldWarehouse);
}
```

Then you can get your mapper in the `partialUpdate()` function and use it this way:

```java
public void partialUpdate(Integer id, Warehouse updatedWarehouse) 
{ 
    Warehouse oldWarehouse = findById(id); 
    
    WarehouseMapper mapperInstance = Mappers.getMapper( WarehouseMapper.class );

    mapperInstance.updateWarehouse(updatedWarehouse, oldWarehouse); // Maps the NON NULL fields of updatedWarehouse to oldWarehouse fields
    
    warehouseRepository.save(oldWarehouse); 
}
```

## OR

Do the mapping yourself and do not use any external dependencies:

```java
public void partialUpdate(Integer id, Warehouse updatedWarehouse) 
{ 
    Warehouse oldWarehouse = findById(id); 
    
    if(updatedWarehouse.getLocation() != null)
    {
        oldWarehouse.setLocation(updatedWarehouse.getLocation());
    }
    
    // ... And so on for each field
    
    warehouseRepository.save(oldWarehouse); 
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant answer that confirmed my thought... thank you very much! I think I'll use the 2nd proposition, worth to touch code without dependencies and in the future, start to work dependencies!